# Weaving different sized lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have different lists such as:

```
a = ['1a', '2a', '3a']

b = ['1b', '2b', '3b']

c = ['1c', '2c', '3c']
```

I'm trying to weave them in a single list such that it has one element of each list successively. I managed to do this for this example with this bit:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b, c)))
```

Which produces the desired output:

```
['1a', '1b', '1c', '2a', '2b', '2c', '3a', '3b', '3c']
```

However, as soon as any list has a different number of elements, the result is cropped by the shortest one, for example if `c = ['1c', '2c']` then the result is:

```
['1a', '1b', '1c', '2a', '2b', '2c']
```

I would like to have every single element in the resulting list. If any of the sublists have less elements it should just skip it, not crop the whole thing.

I've thought of a very simple solution, which is to fill in the short lists with dummy elements so that all of them have the same size:

```
l = [['1a', '2a'], ['1b'], ['1c', '2c', '3c']]
max_len = max([len(x) for x in l])
l = [x + [''] * (max_len - len(x)) for x in l]
```

And then simply filter them out:

```
[e for e in itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*l)) if e != '']
```

Which produces what we want:

```
['1a', '1b', '1c', '2a', '2c', '3c']
```

But I wonder if there is a simpler and more elegant way to do this with itertools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `zip` to `itertools.izip_longest` which will just produce `None` when any of the iterators run out. Then `filter` to remove those:

```
a = ['1a', '2a']
b = ['1b']
c = ['1c', '2c', '3c']
list(filter(None, itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip_longest(a, b, c))))
# ['1a', '1b', '1c', '2a', '2c', '3c']
```

Note: The name changes to `zip_longest` in Python 3.

Comment: Well that'd be `izip_longest` on Python 2.7, but yeah, that was it, thanks!

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice the `2.7` tag. Updated!